# Extend Array of generic objects in swift

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to write an extension to array of generic type in swift. This is how I tried to do this:

```
class Observer<Type> {
    private(set) weak var observer: AnyObject?
    private var listener: (_ newValue: Type) -> ()

    init(observer: AnyObject, listener: @escaping (_ newValue: Type) -> ()) {
        self.observer = observer
        self.listener = listener
    }
}

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Observer<Type> {
    func foo<Type>(value: Type) {
        forEach { $0.listener(value) }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to execute function with parameter of this generic type. Is there any way to write such extension? Later this would look something like this:

```
let observers = [Observer<Int>]()
observers.forEach { $0.foo(4) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't match your implementation. What is `foo`? And how does it relate to `a`? I'm going to make a guess here that you mean this to be:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Observer<Type> {
    func foo<Type>(value: Type) {
        forEach { $0.listener(value) }
    }
}
```

And then later:

```
let observers = [Observer<Int>]()
observers.foo(value: 4)
```

You cannot attach an extension to a Collection based on a specific Element. That's a restriction on extensions that has nothing to do with whether `Observer` is generic. You can't use `==` in the `where` clause. But you can use a protocol.

```
protocol Observing {
    associatedtype ObservingType

    var listener: (_ newValue: ObservingType) -> () { get }
}
```

Then mark Observer as Observing:

```
class Observer<ObservingType>: Observing {
    private(set) weak var observer: AnyObject?
    var listener: (_ newValue: ObservingType) -> ()
```

I've made two other changes. I swapped `Type` for `ObservingType` because `Type` is a keyword (so it's a bit confusing). Also, `listener` cannot be private unless the extension is also private.

OK, given that:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Observing {
    func foo(value: Iterator.Element.ObservingType) {
        forEach { $0.listener(value) }
    }
}

let observers = [Observer<Int>]()
observers.foo(value: 4)
```

Comment: You're right a() was suppose to be foo() - corrected.
And that's it, using associatedtype and protocol was what I needed. Thank you.